# How to represent same table (with different values) in a 1:N relationship with two other tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

[image]

I have three tables:

- `Guardian`
- `Student`
- `Address`

One `Guardian` may have many `Addresses` and one `Student` may have many `Addresses`.

Observations:

- `Guardian` addresses can be exactly the same as the `Students`
- `Guardian` addresses can be different from the `Student`'s

This:

`addressLine1`=Foo, `addressLine2`=Bar (**Student**)

is different from this

`addressLine1`=Foo, `addressLine2`=Bar (**Guardian**)

Just pointing out:

1. One `Guardian` has many `Students` attached to it
2. One `Student` has many `Guardians` attached to it

`Guardian` and `Students` has common attributes as well as specific ones.

Right now, I'm mapping as the snippet below:

```
CREATE TABLE address 
  ( 
     id          BIGINT, 
     /* OTHER FIELDS OMITTED */ 
     guardian_id BIGINT, 
     student_id  BIGINT, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  ) 


CREATE TABLE guardian 
  ( 
     id BIGINT, 
     /* OTHER FIELDS OMITTED */ 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  ) 

CREATE TABLE student 
  ( 
     id BIGINT, 
     /* OTHER FIELDS OMITTED */ 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  ) 

ALTER TABLE address 
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_id FOREIGN KEY (guardian_id) 
  REFERENCES guardian 

ALTER TABLE address 
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_id FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES 
  student
```

Is this the right way? I mean, there's a better solution to this case?

*Address is not a join table if im correct. It's not made for relationship purposes. It has it's own specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gardian -- M:M -- Address
Student -- M:M -- Address
```

You need two additional link tables like `guardian_adresses` and `student_adresses` to model this.

Comment: by doing so, I do create a M:M relationship, didn't I?

Comment: exactly, as you mentioned the M:M is required in your case, not 1:M. In the real world there are cases when something is in M:1 or even 1:1 with addresses but never 1:M. The M:M is the common case. At least every address link has its proper attributes like "home", "work" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't two students or two guardians have the same address?  You model limits this to one of each type.

You need junction/association tables for the two entities.  I would write this as:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses ( 
    addrees_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    . . . 
);

CREATE TABLE guardians ( 
    guardian_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
    . . .
);

CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
     /* OTHER FIELDS OMITTED */ 
); 

CREATE TABLE guardian_addresses (
    guardian_address_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    guardian_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    address_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    . . .  -- other information such a date and who added
    constraint guardian_addresses_guardians foreign key (guardian_id) references guardians(guardian_id),
    constraint guardian_addresses_addresses foreign key (address_id) references addresses(address_id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_addresses (
    student_address_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    address_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    . . .  -- other information such a date and who added
    constraint student_addresses_guardians foreign key (student_id) references students(student_id),
    constraint student_addresses_addresses foreign key (address_id) references addresses(address_id)
);
```

You'll notice that this includes some other conventions:

- Tables are named in the plural, because they contain multiple copies of the entities.
- The primary keys are named in the singular with `_id` at the end.  That way, foreign key references generally use the same column name.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is inline.